# Determine event name from EventHandler<T> in C#

Tags: c#, events, logging, eventhandler

My question is if I can determine an event's name passed through a parameter with EventHandler type? With some code it becomes more clear:

```
public void RaiseEvent<T>(EventHandler<T> eventToRaise, T args) where T : EventArgs, IXmlConvertable
    {
        Log(eventToRaise.Method.Name, args.ToXElement());
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((e) => eventToRaise(this, args));
    }

public event EventHandler<ProductLeftEventArgs> ProductLeftEvent = delegate { };
```

As you can see I want to create a method that not only calls the event async, but also logs the action. IXmlConvertable is a custom interface, which is used for logging. I call the method like this:

```
this.RaiseEvent(this.ProductLeftEvent, new ProductLeftEventArgs() { ... });
```

What I would like to gain is a string with "ProductLeftEvent". Unfortunately the  eventToRaise.Method.Name gives the string "DeliverEvent". Do you think it is possible to achieve this name? It also worth mention, that I use weak event manager when I assing a handler.

Comment: What is `DeliverEvent`? How is it related to the code you posted?

Comment: That is a good question. I don't know. The only thing I know that it is the value of the `eventToRaise.Method.Name` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eventToRise` parameter is a delegate - i.e. reference to a method (and a target or object on which this method should be called). Event holds a reference to all methods that were subscribed to that event.

So in your case it seems that "DeliverEvent" is the method that was attached to your event in some other part of the application like this: `someObject.ProductLeftEvent += this.DeliverEvent;`

If you really want to pass event itself to the `RaiseEvent` method you either need to use expressions or simply pass an eventName (but this will be a kind of duplication).

Below is an example of how to use expressions to do this:

```
public void RaiseEvent<T>(Expression<Func<EventHandler<T>>> eventToRaise, T args) where T : EventArgs, IXmlConvertable
{
    string eventName = ((MemberExpression)eventToRaise.Body).Member.Name;
    Log(eventName, args.ToXElement());
    EventHandler<T> eventHandler = eventToRaise.Compile()();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((e) => eventHandler(this, args));
}
```

You will call this method like this:

```
this.RaiseEvent(() => this.ProductLeftEvent, new ProductLeftEventArgs() { ... });
```

Comment: @Attila Szobonya: Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Sorry it took so long. I tried your code and it does exactly what I wanted. I think it is a quite clever solution. Marked as answer. Thanks. :)